# junit - test won't run and receiving lots of errors

Tags: java, ruby, testing, junit

I have downloaded my old project that was built on a different computer. I have Java environment installed on the current one. I have also downloaded junit to get things work. When I run my tests using build.rb and run_test.rb - files that worked previously, I receive lots of errors negating the entire code. Here's the example

```
$ ruby build.rb
shop_basket\Cashdesk.java:4: error: class CashDesk is public, should be 
declared in a file named CashDesk.java
public class CashDesk{
   ^
1 error
shop_basketSpec\CashdeskTest.java:5: error: class CashDeskTest is public, 
should be declared in a file named CashDeskTest.java
public class CashDeskTest{
   ^
shop_basketSpec\BasketTest.java:2: error: package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.*;
^
shop_basketSpec\BasketTest.java:3: error: package org.junit does not exist
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
                   ^
shop_basketSpec\CashdeskTest.java:2: error: package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.*;
^
shop_basketSpec\CashdeskTest.java:3: error: package org.junit does not exist
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
                   ^
shop_basketSpec\CashdeskTest.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
CashDesk cashdesk;
 ^
symbol:   class CashDesk
location: class CashDeskTest
shop_basketSpec\CustomerTest.java:2: error: package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.*;
^
 shop_basketSpec\CustomerTest.java:3: error: package org.junit does not 
 exist
 import static org.junit.Assert.*;   ^
 shop_basketSpec\ProductTest.java:2: error: package org.junit does not exist
 import org.junit.*;
  ^
```

and there are more errors like this as if they concerned the entire code structure. I don't get why.
All the CLASSPATH etc seems to be set on my windows OS. The entire thing irritates as I cannot move with my coding. Thanks for help

Here's my set CLASSPATH
[CLASSPATH image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm7dT.jpg)

The content of my ruby files

run_tests.rb

```
require 'find'

def find_valid_files
  files = []
  Find.find('bin') do |path|
  files << path if path.include?(".class") && path.include?("Test")
end
return files
end

def run_tests(files)
  for file in files
   fileName = File.basename(file, ".*")
   puts "Running #{fileName}"

  system("java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore #{fileName}")
 end
 end

valid_files = find_valid_files()

Dir.chdir "bin"

run_tests(valid_files)
```

build.rb

```
require 'fileutils'

def filter_directories

  excluded_directories = ["bin"]

  all_files = Dir.glob('*')

 return all_files.select do |file|
   next if excluded_directories.include?(file)
   File.directory?(file)
 end
end

def create_bin
  FileUtils.rm_rf('bin')
  FileUtils.mkdir_p('bin')
end

def run_tests directories
  for directory in directories 
    puts "building #{directory}"
   system("javac -d bin #{directory}/*.java")
  end
end

create_bin()

valid_directories = filter_directories()

run_tests(valid_directories)
```

Comment: Maybe you previously built on Windows and now copied the files to Linux, where file names are case-sensitive (and should match class names). Also, the JUnit jar does not appear to be in the classpath.

Comment: but it seems to be in the classpath. When I type the set CLASSPATH command on prompt, I get the entire path leading to junit.jar file. I use bash to run the file...maybe that's the problem

Comment: @MickMnemonic - even though file names are not case-sensitive on Windows, Java still requires that class names and file names match exactly, regardless of which platform you're on.

Comment: @bwielk That's a good theory - what happens if you explicitly set it in your Bash script or terminal?

Answer (score 0):

For the first two errors relating to CashDesk and CashDeskTest - your file names have a lowercase 'd' (Cashdesk.java and CashdeskTest.java).  The casing in the file name should match the actual class names as declared in the code.  Fix that.

If you still see JUnit errors afterwards, check that you have a JUnit JAR on your classpath.

Comment: I have already done it earlier and it's still not working. when I type set CLASSPATH on command prompt, I get the entire path of the junit.jar file

Comment: How are you trying to compile this code?  Via an IDE or on the command line?  I would try to see what happens when you specify the classpath explicitly when you compile it (the -cp argument on the command line).

Comment: I am compiling it using bash that is set for ruby and java.

Comment: I have just attached an image showing that the CLASSPATH is set right.

Answer (score 0):

Errors `Cashdesk.java:4: error: class CashDesk is public, should be 
declared in a file named CashDesk.java` are caused by inconsistency between .java file names and public class which it contains. In this exaple class CashDesk is saved in `Cashdesk.java` file - note d vs D in Desk.

The second bunch of errors `error: package org.junit does not exist` mean you should include JUnit library to the classpath of your project

Comment: what do you mean by "the classpath OF MY PROJECT"? :) my classpath says it's set to junit.jar

Comment: I mean the CP for your program. If you are getting junit not found error - this definately means this library is not found in the classpath. It may be wise to post  contents of you *.rb files

Comment: I have just attached an image showing my set CLASSPATH

Comment: and I have attached the contents of the rb files